# Django Sessions table displaying only admin id

Tags: python, django, session

sessions

```
Session key
session data
Expire date
    z8mmy56dgxtw7kiohhsczvdfugydt958    {}  Oct. 12, 2017, 10:50 p.m.
    bnxre1r8muapvy1znvqu0msectghm2vm    {u'_auth_user_hash': u'ca7e738308ed261de83fe3c80c9a4657b37e8c81', u'_auth_user_id': u'2', u'_auth_user_backend': u'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'}  Oct. 12, 2017, 10:14 p.m.
    0erbl0nmfsj4vzczubslpea3eagyzroe    {u'_auth_user_hash': u'ca7e738308ed261de83fe3c80c9a4657b37e8c81', u'_auth_user_id': u'2', u'_auth_user_backend': u'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'}  Oct. 12, 2017, 11:21 p.m.
```

I have three users in my CustomUser(AbstractUser) table but no matter which one is logged in, the auth_user_id shows id=2 that is the id of the superuser admin. The other two ids are not shown. what is wrong here?

I have not handled sessions explicitly. i have used django's inbuilt auth system using AbstractUser.

Comment: How are logging the user in?

Comment: by django.contrib.auth.views.login and django.contrib.auth.views.logout

Comment: Because that user is logged-in that time. So Django store that user id, hash, backend in encrypted form in session.
A single session of Django can't store multiple user ID. Because one user can log in your browser tab at a time

Comment: i've changed users who are logged in...then also it shows the same id.

Comment: i'm not talking about multiple users logged in at a single time..

Comment: If you changed user then that user id will update in session. because when user log out that time Django flush all session in request and after login it'll store logged-in user id in session.

Comment: that is exactly what is not happening here...even if say id=3 is logged in, the sessions table is not showing that...it still shows id=2. i think the sessions table is not connected to my CustomUser table...when i refresh the admin page(django admin), it shows a new session key. But since only admin can login the django admin page, it shows id=2 because in my table, admin has id=2.